# InstantiationException: has no zero argument constructor?

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a location address in google map but when i start Intent Service for the fetching address it will show error "Unable to instantiate service" .

i use this link for Displaying a Location Address.

```
https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html
```

this is my code:

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public FetchAddressIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String errorMessage="";

        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);



        List<Address> addresses=null;

        try {
            addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorMessage="unhendle IO exception";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(addresses==null && addresses.size()==0){
            if(errorMessage.isEmpty()){
                errorMessage="no address found";
            }

            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        }
        else{

            Address address=addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> arrayListFrag=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0;i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++){

                arrayListFrag.add(address.getAddressLine(0));
            }

            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                            arrayListFrag));

        }
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int successResult, String message) {
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY,message);
        mReceiver.send(successResult,bundle);
    }
}
```

here i start intent Service:

```
 protected void startIntentService(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA,mLastLocation);
        startService(intent);
    }


   public void fetchAddressButtonHandler(){
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mLastLocation!=null){
            startIntentService();
        }

   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63651986/3496570

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
public FetchAddressIntentService(String name) {
  super(name);
}
```

with:

```
public FetchAddressIntentService() {
  super("whatever you want to use here");
}
```

(replacing the string with something suitable for your app)

Comment: onHandleIntent(Intent intent) automatically call by service??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an zero argument constructor to your class FetchAddressIntentService that takes no arguments:

```
public FetchAddressIntentService() {
    super("FetchAddressIntentService");
}
```

Comment: onHandleIntent(Intent intent) automatically call by service??