# ViewModel has no zero argument constructor error - even when it has a zero argument constructor

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-fusedlocation

I'm new to Android and Java and am trying to make a location-based app.

**EDIT**

I've made a much, much simpler test code and get the same error. Here's the java:

```
package com.example.viewmodeltest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
        public int scoreTeamA = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyViewModel locationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

I get the same error. Here are the dependencies in my app-level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //dependencies for ViewModel, LiveData, etc.
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm attempting to use ViewModel and LiveData to update the user location as I understand that's the best way to be lifecycle-aware. I have a default maps activity...

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {...}
```

A class which extends LiveData to store the user location...

```
public class LocationLiveData extends LiveData<Location> {
        private final Context context;
        private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;

        public LocationLiveData(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        }

        private void setLocationData(Location location) {
            Location value = new Location("SetInternal");
            value.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            value.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            setValue(value);
        }

        protected void createLocationRequest() {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }

        private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    setLocationData(location);
                }
            }
        };

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            createLocationRequest();
            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onInactive() {
            super.onInactive();
            fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActive() {
            super.onActive();
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            if (location != null)
                                setValue(location);
                        }
                    });
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
```

And a class which extends ViewModel to allow the main activity to reach the LocationLiveData.

```
 public class LocationViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private LocationLiveData locationLiveData;

        public LocationViewModel () {
            locationLiveData = new LocationLiveData(getApplicationContext());
        }

        public LocationLiveData getLocationLiveData() {
            return locationLiveData;
        }
    }
```

Then when I attempt to make an instance of locationViewModel in the onMapReady method:

```
LocationViewModel locationViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LocationViewModel.class);
```

I get an error on that line:

> Cannot create an instance of class com.example.MapsActivity$LocationViewModel
>
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor

I get this error even if I take out the constructor entirely in locationViewModel, and also if I attempt to extend AndroidViewModel instead.

Any ideas? I've seen other similar queries but the answer has always been to take arguments out of the constructor - which I've already done!

Thanks a lot for any  help

Comment: "And a class which extends ViewModel to allow the main activity to reach the LocationLiveData" -- I would not expect that to compile, as [there is no `getApplicationContext()` method in `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel). Is `LocationViewModel` perhaps declared as an inner class of something else, like an activity, that does have a `getApplicationContext()` method?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I've edited the post with a more simple test code that doesn't involve that getApplicationContext() line and I get the same error.

Re: the getApplicationContext, my original approach was to pass a context into the LocationViewModel instead, but I took this out to get a zero-argument constructor. I don't have any classes other than those stated, and this is my only activity so far!

Comment: @CommonsWare - wondering if you could offer one more piece of advice. I'm looking to alter the frequency of location updates based on how close the user is to a given point (dynamically set in the UI). In onMapReady I am observing the LocationLiveData. I thought I could either have a locationRequest LiveData object which is updated by my oberver and is itself observed within LocationLiveData; or my observer could invoke a locationViewModel method which invokes a LocationLiveData method to restart updates with some new parameters. Any idea which (if either) is more robust?

Comment: Sorry, but I guess I do not understand your situation. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

- Move `MyViewModel` to a separate Java file, or
- Make `MyViewModel` be a `static class`

Right now, you have defined `MyViewModel` as an inner class of `MainActivity`. That will not work, as only an instance of `MainActivity` can create an instance of `MyViewModel`. In particular, `ViewModelProvider` cannot create an instance of `MyViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was indeed the issue! Worked for the toy example, and then after a couple of adjustments the real code worked too. As you said, getApplicationContext() didn't work once I made LocationViewModel a static class, so I gave the LocationViewModel a method called setContext, where in the main code I could just pass it the application context (in case this is useful to anyone).

Comment: You could also switch back to `AndroidViewModel`, which handles the case where you need a `Context`. In particular, it forces you to use the `Application` as the `Context`, preventing you from accidentally using the `Activity` as the `Context` and causing a memory leak. But, regardless, I'm glad that it is working for you!

Answer (score 14):

> **while using hilt I am facing the same issue when I forgot to add**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
```

above the **activity declaration**

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
       public int scoreTeamA = 0;
    }
}
```

This makes `MyViewModel` an inner class of `MainActivity`, meaning it has an implicit reference to the outer class (as per the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)) and cannot be constructed separately from `MainActivity`. This effectively means that in bytecode, its constructor always takes an instance of `MainActivity` - even if you don't write out that constructor.

You can make your inner class a static nested class by adding the `static` keyword. This removes the implicit reference to the outer class and makes it similar to any other top level class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
       public int scoreTeamA = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, making MyViewModel a static class fixed the issue. I didn't really know what the static keyword meant so thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

in my case did forget to add
`HasSupportFragmentInjector` to my `Activity` !!!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppComaptActivity
        implements HasSupportFragmentInjector{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;


    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using hilt. You seem to have forgotten to mention the annotation "@AndroidEntryPoint" in the class. This mistake happened in my case too.

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
```

[image]